# using wp_remote_get to retrieve own url on local host

Tags: http, http-api, wp-remote-get

I have a website in local development at test:8888 and I am trying to get the following to work in my functions.php file.

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'test:8888/?p=1' );
print_r($response);
```

Unfortunately this is printing

```
WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [http_request_failed] => Array ( [0] => A valid URL was not provided. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )
```

Is it possible to request your own url while developing on localhost?

Answer (score 4):

### Ad Timeout

You should be able to get around the timeout using a filter

```
add_filter( 'http_request_timeout', 'wpse35826_timeout_extd' );
function wpse35826_timeout_extd( $time )
{
    // Default timeout is 5
    return 10;
}
```

### Choose the right protocol/scheme

About your protocol/scheme problem: If it's your local install, you can use the conditional.

```
function wpse35826_remote_get( $args )
{
    $protocol = is_SSL() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    $response = wp_remote_get( "{$protocol}test:8888/?p=1" );
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) )
        return "{$response->get_error_code()}: {$response->get_error_message()}";

    return print htmlspecialchars( var_export( $response, true ) );
}

// Trigger the request
wpse35826_remote_get();
```

If you're doing requests *to your **own** local server*, then there might be a problem with the SSL verification. WP uses a filter to trigger it's setting:

```
add_filter( 'https_local_ssl_verify', '__return_false' );
```

This filter *does not(!)* trigger for local servers doing requests to a server on the web. For external servers use the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'https_ssl_verify', '__return_false' );
```

### Issues with local requests

Then there also can be issues with blocked local request:

```
add_filter( 'block_local_requests', '__return_false' );
```

Other things that can be influencing your ability to do local requests are constants set wrong in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL
// If WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL is defined you can add hosts which shouldn't be blocked.
WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS
```

In case you're using Proxies:

```
// Allows you to define some adresses which shouldn't be passed through a proxy.
// Core sets both www and non-www as bypass.
// get_option('siteurl') and localhost are bypassed by default.
WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS
```

### No cURL?

If there's `cURL` not available and you're not streaming data to a file, WP will fallback to using `Fsocketopen()` instead. From a core comment, which sums it up nicely:

> Fsocketopen has issues with 'localhost' with IPv6 with certain versions of PHP, It attempts to connect to ::1, which fails when the server is not set up for it. For compatibility, always connect to the IPv4 address.

Point is, that WP only jumps in if we got the host name `localhost`. The fsocketopen host will then get set to `'127.0.0.1'`.

Comment: Excellent answer! The magic for me was changing from `http://localhost` to `http://127.0.0.1` - no other parts of this answer mattered after I made that change.

Answer (score 1):

'test:8888/?p=1' isn't a valid URL.

Try 'http://test:8888/?p=1' instead.

Comment: that gives this WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [http_request_failed] => Array ( [0] => Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

Comment: I am running MAMP

Comment: Is "test:8888" a valid URL on your machine? There's no problem with accessing local resources, but those resources must actually exist and be accessible.

Comment: yes, that resolves fine on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it like this:

```
function wpse35826_remote_get() {
    $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://test:8888/?p=1' );
    echo 'Response:<pre>';
    print_r($response);
    echo '</pre>';
}
add_action('admin_init','wpse35826_remote_get');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually have two problems here. Otto's answer solved your first problem, because leaving the `http://` off made it an invalid URL, which is why you got the `A valid URL was not provided` error.

The second problem is something different and unrelated, and is giving you the `Operation timed out` error. I can't say for sure without seeing your entire code, but I'm guessing that the `wp_remote_get()` call is inside a callback function which is registered to a hook that is also firing on the page that's being requested by `wp_remote_get()`. That situation creates a recursive loop that ultimately times out.

You need to make sure that `wp_remote_get()` call isn't being fired on the page that you're requesting. You can do that by registering the callback to a different hook, or by using [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to avoid calling `wp_remote_get()` on the requested page.

Here's an example, assuming you'll always be calling non-admin pages:

```
if( !is_admin() )
    return;

$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://test:8888/?p=1' );
print_r($response);
```